# How do I get a FlatList to show correct items when I open the screen?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-native-flatlist

The idea is to have a toggle switch that switches from **To Watch** and **Watched** bookings. When I update a movie in the **To Watch** list, I want it to rerender the FlatList without that booking because it's now in the **Watched** list. And so when I press the toggle to see the **Watched** list I would now see the booking there. Same for reverse.

I have to press the toggle twice to see the change. Even **when I open the screen for the first time it shows all the movies without the filter** - this is the main thing I'm having trouble with. How can I get around this? This is the code I have:

```
const WatchList = () => {

  const uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
  const docRef = doc(db, 'users', uid);
  const [user, setUser] = useState({});
  const [watched, setWatched] = useState(true);
  const [text, setText] = useState('To watch');
  const [filteredBookings, setFilteredBookings] = useState(bookings);

  const bookingsRef = collection(db, "booking"); // imamo ref ka bazi

  const [bookings, setBookings] = useState({});
   useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
    getBookings();
  },[])

  const getUser = async () => {
    const snap = await getDoc(docRef)
    setUser({user, ...snap.data()})
  }

  const getBookings = async () =>{
    const q = query(bookingsRef, where("users","array-contains",auth.currentUser.uid));
      const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (querySnapshot) => {
        const a = [];
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {            
        a.push(doc.data());
      });
      setBookings(querySnapshot.docs);
    });
  }

  const toggleSwitch = () =>{
    if(!watched){
      setFilteredBookings(bookings.filter(function(item){
        return item.data().watched == true;
      }))
      setText('Watched');
    } else {
      setText('To watch');
      setFilteredBookings(bookings.filter(function(item){
        return item.data().watched == false;
      }))
    }
    setWatched(previousState => !previousState);
  }

  const updateBooking = async(id) => {
    try {
      await setDoc(doc(db, 'booking', id), {
        watched: true
      }, {merge: true})
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  const updateBooking1 = async(id) => {
    try {
      await setDoc(doc(db, 'booking', id), {
        watched: false
      }, {merge: true})
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  const deleteBooking = async(id) => {
    try {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, 'booking', id));
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const resultOfFiltering = bookings
    setFilteredBookings(resultOfFiltering)
  }, [bookings])

  return (
    <View>
      <View>
        <Text>{text}</Text>
        <Switch 
          value = {watched}
        />
      </View>
  
  <FlatList
    data = {filteredBookings}
    extraData = {watched}

    renderItem  = {({item}) => (
      <View>
      <View>
        <Text>{item.data().movie}</Text>
        <Text>{item.data().day} - {item.data().showtime}</Text>
      </View>
      <View>
        {item.data().watched == true ? (
            <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.delete} onPress = {() => {updateBookings(item.id); setFilteredBookings();}}>
            <Image source={require('../assets/watched.png')}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {updateBookings1(item.id); setFilteredBookings();}}>
        <Image source={require('../assets/towatch.png')}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>)}

        <TouchableOpacity onPress = {() => {deleteBooking(item.id); setFilteredBookings();}}>
          <Image source={require('../assets/remove.png')}/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      </View>
    )}
  />
      </View>
  )
}

export default WatchList
```

It's not really working properly at the moment and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong so I'm kind of stuck. If I could get some help, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you!